# why my spring data es cannot resolve the method 'boolFilter()'

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring data elasticsearch, the version extends the spring boot parent module ie 2.0.2 release, and I have imported the class as this

`import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;`

but when I use the `boolFilter()`,then got this error :

> cannot resolve the method boolFilter()

How can I fix it?

Comment: I got the same problem, have any solution?

Comment: @jzonz did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see `boolFilter()` in `QueryBuilders`, use `boolQuery()` instead.

Comment: You are right. This should be a "bug" in the Spring-Data documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc.filter